# inserting into an array in foreach

Tags: c#, arrays, redirect, insert

I have the following code. I'm doing some work on websites, but sometimes they redirect, and if they do so I want to do the work on the redirected site. BUT I don't want to check all the sites for redirection before doing the work, as there are few of them. So how can I insert it in the loop? I know that I can't insert into string array, but what's the best structure? Probably list, because of insert, although I'm not so keen to hold on to the values, which we have already processed. I'm not proficient in C#.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"my_file_with_urls.txt");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
  Uri default_uri = new Uri(line);
  Uri response;

  WebSiteIsAvailable(default_uri, out response); 

  //Do work on the actual link

  if (!response.Host.Equals(default_uri.Host)){
    //I want to run the work on the redirected website
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Is there some sort of error?

Comment: What you want to insert ? can't you make a separate list and append it later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var urisToProcess = new HashSet<Uri>(
  lines.Where(s => Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(s, UriKind.Absolute)).Select(s => new Uri(s)));
var redirectedUris = new HashSet<Uri>();
foreach (var uri in urisToProcess)
{
  Uri response;    
  WebSiteIsAvailable(uri, out response); 
  if(response.Equals(uri))
  {
    // do work on actual URI
    continue;
  }
  while (!response.Equals(uri))
  {    
    uri = response;
    WebSiteIsAvailable(uri, out response); 
  }
  if(!urisToProcess.Contains(uri))
  {
     redirectedUris.Add(uri);
  }
}
foreach (var uri in redirectedUris)
{
  // do work on redirected URI
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Hashset solves my other problem of duplicated line :) BTW if you convert all lines into uris, and one line is not a proper Uri, I get an exception. But only for the first line, how to handle properly all malformed urls?

Comment: you can use Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uriString, UriKind.Absolute), I  have updated my answer.

Comment: cool. thanks. How can I extract the non-wellformed urls too? I want to know them, so not to loose any data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try, I havent fully tested it, but.

```
foreach (string line in lines) 
{   
 Uri default_uri = new Uri(line);   
 Uri response;    
 WebSiteIsAvailable(default_uri, out response);     

 while (!response.Host.Equals(default_uri.Host))
 {    
  default_uri = response;
  WebSiteIsAvailable(default_uri, out response); 
 } 

 //Do work on the actual link as now default_uri contains the working link.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert items in the array or list you are going through with foreach. Instead make a for loop and decrease the index of the loop.